# Link a view to another view

Tags: views

I have a view block and I want to add a field link so that will displays a view of the content types that I have create not a content type itself is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put almost anything you want in a Views Header or Footer, so if you added a Global Text Area field there, you could put in a link to a page display of a view that shows your content types, and that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display more detail you can use attachment option in views.